# laravel: module dirty commit

Tags: php, git, laravel, paypal

I have a project which main framework is Laravel.
So I installed [netshell/paypal](https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal) through `composer` and after that I've continued developing, ignoring a `git diff` which describes a dirty commit for paypal.

Anyways after some commits I've found the issue on a pre-production server, and more precisely the content was not pushed to it. It was just the container.

I've tried to remove that directory from the local machine and pushed again but the same dirty commit happens. I'm asking you how to fix.

It seems that issue is under working tree.

Thank you & have a nice day,
stykky

Comment: Did you commit your `vendor` directory to Git? If so, why? (There is generally no need to do so: just commit your `composer.json` and `composer.lock`.)

Comment: I've changed some files under `vendor` directory and cause that the vendor is pushed and not fetched throught `composer`

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem it should be reinstalled every dirty module with dependences as well. If it throws any error, remove manually every module and dependences & settings under `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and `composer/autoload_*` files.

Thank you,
stykky